# passing data from php to python in laravel 5

Tags: php, python, laravel-5

So i have seen other questions like this, but what i have seen isn't working and i'm not sure if its a laravel 5 thing or not.

i have a python file -  jobs.py:

```
import yaml
import requests
import os
import inspect
import sys
import datetime
import random
import urllib2
import cPickle 



print "hey"
print sys.argv[1]
print str(sys.argv)
```

In the normal linux command line if I type in the following:

> python
>   /home/mscarpa/PhpstormProjects/quasar-node/quasar-node/quasar-node/src/lib/jobs.py
>   arg1 arg2

I will get this response as expected:

> hey
>       arg1
>       ['/home/mscarpa/PhpstormProjects/quasar-node/quasar-node/quasar-node/src/lib/jobs.py',
>   'arg1', 'arg2']

But when i try to do the same thing in my php file:

```
public function getJobs()
{
    $jobs = \App\Job::all();
    $var1 = "arg1";
    $command = exec('python /home/mscarpa/PhpstormProjects/quasar-node/quasar-node/quasar-node/src/lib/jobs.py  $var1');
    return view('jobs/jobs_table', compact('jobs'));
}
```

And start using xdebug to see what is going on it says that its connected when its steps over $command but $command only returns "hey". I am trying to pass $var1='arg1' to the python script.

Thanks

Comment: $var1 will not be interpreted unless you use double quotes. (I mean `"python /home/mscarpa/PhpstormProjects/quasar-node/quasar-node/quasar-node/src/lib/jobs.py  $var1"`)

Comment: A. Mazing. I was panicking. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Python is not receiving the contents of `$var1`, because when using a string with single quotes, as in

```
$command = exec('python /home/.../src/lib/jobs.py  $var1');
```

any contained variables will not be parsed. You must use double quotes like this:

```
$command = exec("python /home/.../src/lib/jobs.py  $var1");
```

You can read about variable parsing [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Comment: I'm not sure where `$var1` is coming from but if it's user input, be sure to escape it using `escapeshellarg()`